# Get date via JS and add class?

Tags: javascript

I want to detect the current day and after that, add active to a class, to highlight the current day.

```
var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDay();
    if ( day == 'Montag' ){
        $(".monday").addClass("active");
    }
    if ( day == 'Dienstag' ){
        $(".tuesday").addClass("active");
    }
    if ( day == 'Mittwoch' ){
        $(".wednesday").addClass("active");
    }
    if ( day == 'Donnerstag' ){
        $(".thursday").addClass("active");
    }
    if ( day == 'Freitag' ){
        $(".friday").addClass("active");
    }
    if ( day == 'Samstag' ){
        $(".saturday").addClass("active");
    }
```

I know, switch would be better.
Thx

Comment: `getDay()` returns an `Integer` from 0 to 6, not a `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDay()` returns a Number from 0 to 6. [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp)

To make your code even better you can store you class names in an array and access it by the index given by `getDay()` and use it directly in your selector:

```js
var days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"];
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDay();
$("." + days[day]).addClass("active");
```

```css
span {
  color: blue;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="monday">Montag</span>
<span class="tuesday">Dienstag</span>
<span class="wednesday">Mittwoch</span>
<span class="thursday">Donnerstag</span>
<span class="friday">Freitag</span>
<span class="saturday">Samstag</span>
<span class="sunday">Sonntag</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that to have a more readable code.

```
var daysOfWeeks = ['sunday', 'monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday'];
var date = new Date();
$('.' + daysOfWeek[date.getDay()]).addClass("active");
```

Remember that [`getDay()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getday.asp) returns an integer between 0 and 6 included (and 0 corresponds to Sunday).

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( day == 1 ){
    $(".monday").addClass("active");
}
...
```

or

```
switch (day) {
  case 1:
    $(".monday").addClass("active");
    break;
  ...
}
```

or

```
var dayClasses = ["sunday", "monday", ...];
$("." + dayClasses[day]).addClass("active");
```